# Preciso atender o Gui 10 da Anvisa que pede uma ponderação específica

Tags: r

O Guia 10 da Agência Nacional de Vigilância Sanitária preconiza que caso as variâncias residuais forem heterocedástica temos que usar o seguinte fator de ponderação:

```
wi=((1/Si^2)/((Somatório de 1/Si^2)/n)
```

Meus dados são:

```
x=c(80,80,80,90,90,90,100,100,100,110,110,110,120,120,120)
y=c(7752365,7747524,7852362,9012556,9322541,9033562,10025368,10025558,10024986,11112541,11022574,10999854,12016525,12021254,12018741)
```

O máximo que eu consegui chegar foi nisso:

```
VarCond <- aggregate(df$y, list(df$x), var)$x
qtde_x <- as.numeric(table(df$x))
pesos <- rep(1/VarCond, qtde_x)
ajustew <- lm(y ~ x, data=df, weights=pesos)
summary(ajustew)
```

Não consigo ir mais além.

Comment: Boa noite! Sugiro que você coloque uma saída esperada dos dados, dessa forma quem for tentar resolver o problema terá onde consultar. Abraço!

Comment: Eu diria que o problema com estes dados não é heterocedasticidade. A dupla de observações (90, 9322541) é um ponto de influência. Ela que parece indicar que a variância dos resíduos não é constante. Ao retirá-la do conjunto de dados (é a 5a. observação), o ajuste fica bem comportado. Eu investigaria melhor o que houve com esse caso e, dependendo da situação, optaria por removê-la, mesmo ficando com um pequeno desbalanceamento no experimento.

Comment: Obrigado Marcus, na verdade esses são dados fictícios criados para rodar o script, o problema é que eu não consigo construir o fator de ponderação conforme solicitação da Anvisa

Answer (score 2):

Do [Guia 10 da ANVISA](http://portal.anvisa.gov.br/documents/10181/2721567/%281%29Guia+10+v1+Tratamento+estatistico+validacao+analitica.pdf/85b0e965-d72f-4b7c-bd2e-17de13af1976), página 9:

> Se os pontos individuais são assinalados por (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)... (xi, yi)... (xn, yn), os desvios padrão correspondentes são *s*1, *s*2, *s*3 ... *s*i ... *s*n. Pode-se, em seguida, definir os pesos individuais, *w*1, *w*2, *w*3 ... *w*i ... *w*n, como sendo:
>
> [image: formula]

Assim:

```
s <- aggregate(y, list(x), sd)$x
n <- length(s)
w <- s^-2 / (sum(s^-2) / n)

pesos <- rep(w, table(x))
ajustew <- lm(y ~ x, weights = pesos)
```